# Why is my avatar so blurry?

Tags: support, bug, profile-picture, winter-bash, gravatar

I have a new monitor which requires a dpi scaling since that date I see that my avatars are blurry and I didn't know why. Now I found it out. There is a bug in url.

Check this screenshot:

[image]

As you can see there two "s" arguments which override the image size. Could you please fix that?

Comment: I doubt that this is a bug; the `s` argument determines what size the gravatar actually is.  I wonder; does mine [look blurry to you?](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c17dd9cf3e2322be19639e96da9f3eb3?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&s=48)

Comment: This is going to auto-fix by January 4th.  I'm starting to hate hats.

Comment: @hans I don't think this is really related with winter bash. I just took the  screenshot there because there was my avatar relatively big and the effect quiet clear to see.

Comment: Yay! My name is there below yours :)

Comment: But you own one or two more then me 

Comment: @rekire how you get into tat page?

Comment: I took the screenshot here: http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/stackoverflow.com

Comment: Maybe you moved your head?

Comment: @Makoto It's clearly a bug, the `s` parameter is passed twice, and the second is overwriting the first.

Comment: @DJDavid98:  Fair point.  Although I'd say that Gravatar's got some cleaning up to do of its API (perhaps it shouldn't be last one wins?), I suppose the real issue is why 48px was chosen for that page when the scaling at least looks okay if 128 is selected.

Comment: @Makoto The fact that the "last one wins" is due to how GET parameters work. The last is usually considered effective.

Comment: @rekire Is it possible to use emoji on comment section or in a post? How?

Comment: @SonerGönül Just write the desired unicode character. In this case, [U+1F609](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f609/index.htm). Some people will see an ugly box instead of the emoticon, though.

Comment: @SonerGönül I used my mobile to write that emoji, but in the end Oriol is right, this is just a unicode character.